# SQL return lowest value for each unique integer value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data similar to this:

```
    loc  dist  value
    1    0.2    2.5
    1    0.5    3.8
    1    0.8    3.4
    1    1.2    5.9
    1    1.4    5.6
    1    1.8    6.2
    1    2.1    7.8
    1    2.4    7.4
```

What I need to be able to read the lowest value for each dist truncated (rounded was a red herring) to a integer. The data is in loc, dist sequence ... the value col is not in sequence

ie the result should give me:

```
loc  dist  value
1    0     2.5
1    1     5.6
1    2     7.4
```

Obviously I can do this in code but i was trying to do this purely in SQL.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You don't want `dist` *rounded* to an integer, but *truncated*. If I round 0.8 I get 1; you want 0.

Comment: floor was the key ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
select floor(dist), min(value) from my_table group by floor(dist)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want round or floor?

```
select loc, round(dist) as dist, min(value) as value
from my_table 
group by loc, round(dist)
order by dist asc
```